# Threads in UML state machine diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram, state-machine

How do I represent execution threads in UML state machine diagram model?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean parallel execution?  i.e. where there are 2 (or more) concurrently executing sub-state machines?  If so like this:

[image]

The top & bottom (sub)state machines in `Superstate` will execute concurrently.

hth.